# Run Universal Application for Device From Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, bootstrapping, windows-10-mobile, lumia

I need to run my Universal Application from Visual Studio 2015 for Device, but when click in "Run" or "Deploy", in ARM architecture, have two errors:

> Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be
>   found. The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet
>   available.
>
> Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during
>   bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device
>   '30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E'.':  DeviceException - The data
>   necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.

My phone (Lumia 535), have build 10581, and my pc have Windows 10 Enterprise.
My pc recognized my phone.
In two devices I activate option Developer Mode.

In emulator it's work fine.

Someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue earlier please try the below steps.

1.Deactivate Hyper-V (and restart computer).
 2.Go in the Device Manager and open the Network Adapters, here uninstall everything with the name "Hyper-V...", this will allow us to reactivate Hyper-V without any conflict.
 3.Activate Hyper-V (and restart computer).

This may help you to figure out the issue.

Comment: Great. Work. Thank :)

Comment: if this solved your question, please mark this as ANSWER!

Comment: [This](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_perf/lumia-640-lte-at-10572-no-longer-found-by-visual/5c60c8d0-a07b-4342-9f98-d292299b430d?auth=1) helped.